# Equation for determining average data transfer speed when day/night throttling limit is different

Tags: average, bandwidth

this may be better posted in Mathematics, but figured someone in StackOverflow may have seen this before. I am trying to devise an equation for determining the average data transfer speed for backup appliances that offsite their data to a data center.

On weekdays during the 8:00a-5:00p hours (1/3 of the day), the connection is throttled to 20% of the measured bandwidth. The remaining 2/3 of the weekday (5:00p-8:00a), the connection is throttled to 80% of the measured bandwidth. On the weekend from Friday 5:00p until Monday 8:00a, the connection is a constant 80% of the measured bandwidth.

The reason behind this is deciding whether to seed the data onto a hard drive versus letting the data transfer over the internet. Making this decision is based on getting a somewhat accurate bandwidth average so that I can calculate the [transfer time](http://www.calctool.org/CALC/prof/computing/transfer_time)

I had issues coming up with an equation, so I reverse engineered a few real world occurrences using *just* the weekday 80%/20% average. I came up with 57.5% of the measured bandwidth, but could not extrapolate an equation from it. Now I want to write a program to determine this. I am thinking factoring in the weekend being 80% the whole time would use a similar equation.

This would be similar scenario to a car travelling at 20% of speed limit for 1/3 of the day and then 80% of speed limit for the rest of that day, and then determine average car speed for the day. I searched online and could not find any reference to an equation for this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the idea you provided, is direct the equation:

> Average = (1/3) * bandwith_1 + (2/3) * bandwith_2

If bandwith_1 = 20 and bandwith_2 = 80, the equation gives a maximumm value of 59,99999%.

Comment: I had arrived at this equation before, but after going over it again, this seems to be correct. I was able to calculate the average including the weekend this time, and arrived at 67%. Now, the challenge will be writing code to figure this out depending on how late in the week it is. Just writing the psuedocode for this has been quite mind bending.